# How to remove personal documents from Amazon?

Tags: amazon, kindle

I got hundreds of personal documents in my Amazon cloud. They were sent to me few times a day from some site which created e-books basing on RSS content.

Removing them through Amazon's personal documents manager would take hours as it refreshes whole page after each deleted file.

[image: Too many personal documents]

How to efficiently remove documents of distinctive title without harming the other ones? Amazon forgot to make it convenient.

Answer (score 1):

**Please note**: The answer was written for the previous Amazon web interface.  I don't know if it still works.

It's tricky. Enable development tools of your browser, usually accessible with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, and go to "Console" tab. Modify the following script to fit your needs (see below), paste into that large field in Console tab and execute it by hitting **Return** or <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Soon, the whole page will reload showing the next portion of documents—repeat whole thing then. I agree it's still cumbersome, but far better than doing it manually.

```
;(function(){

var WORK_ON_PAGE = 1;
var TITLES = ['Bash.org.pl', 'Astronomia.pl', 'Niebezpiecznik.pl'];

var $ = jQuery;
var shouldRemove = function(title) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < TITLES.length; i++) {
    if (TITLES[i] == title) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};

var removeItem = function(item) {
  console.log('removing ' + item);
  Fion.deleteItem('deleteItem_' + item);
};

pageList.gotopage(WORK_ON_PAGE);

$('#orderList tr').each(function(){
  var row = $(this);
  var title = row.find('.headerTitle').text();
  if (shouldRemove(title)) {
    var item = row.find('input[name=contentName]').val();
    removeItem(item);
  }
});

return 'wait for refresh';

})();
```

The above script is configurable. The most important thing is to specify the document titles you want to remove in the 4th line (the one with `TITLES`). `WORK_ON_PAGE` option switches to nth page of the document manager. It's very useful when you have a lot of documents which don't match removal criteria on the first page.

It's possible that you can cycle through all pages with `pageList.gotopage` before removing anything so you can gather info about all documents you want to remove and remove them in once pass. That would be awesome, however I haven't checked that option because I discovered it so late.